# jQuery insertAfter is not a function

Tags: jquery, dom, element, insertafter

I need to insert element to a Dom element outside for each:

```
$items1 = [];
$.each($('.qs-option-name'), function () {
   if($(this).find('span.highlighted').length === 1){
      $item  = $(this).parent().parent();
      console.log($item);
      $items1.push($item);
   }
 });
 console.log($items1);
 $items1.insertAfter('ul li.first');
```

console.log() inside for each:
[image]

console.log() outside for each:

[image]

Not sure looping an array again to insert is efficient is there a way to insert an array of DOM elements in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `$items1` is an array of jQuery objects and therefore does not have a `insertAfter()` method.

To solve this you could create a jQuery object from the array:

```
$($items1).insertAfter('ul li.first');
```

Alternatively you can use `add()` to combine jQuery objects instead of creating a basic array:

```js
var $items1 = $();
$('.qs-option-name').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('span.highlighted').length === 1) {
    $item = $(this).parent().parent();
    $items1.add($item);
  }
});
$items1.insertAfter('ul li.first');
```

However you can make the logic more succinct using `:has()` and `map()`:

```js
var $items1 = $('.qs-option-name:has(span.highlighted)').map(function() {
  return $(this).parent().parent();
}).get();
$items1.insertAfter('ul li.first');
```

Note that the above is slightly different in that `:has()` will match any child, not only a single instance as your original did, but given the context that doesn't seem an important distinction.

Comment: I've also found I can use `prepend` But i give it try create object form array as you sugested!